# Explicit description of a two-point stabilizer of the symplectic groups $Sp(2k,2)$ over $GF(2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, symplectic-linear-algebra

Working with Dixon and Mortimer's "Permutation Groups", we get explicit descriptions of two-point stabilizers of most of the infinite families of the two-transitive permutation groups. For example, we can readily determine the two-point stabilizers of $AGL(k,n)$, $PGL(k,n)$, $PSU(3,n)$, $Sz(2^{2k+1})$, and $Ree(3^{2k+1})$ on the corresponding affine spaces, projective spaces, isotropic spaces, or Steiner systems.

In the same book, there is a description of the two distinct two-transitive actions of $Sp(2k,2)$, which is well known to be the same as its actions on the sets of cosets of its two maximal orthogonal subgroups. There it is stated that $Sp(2k,2)$ is generated by transvections whenever $k\geq 3$. I tried to work out the form of the matrices in a two-point stabilizer $Sp(2k,2)_{\theta_a,\theta_b}$ through these generators. Even though I determined which transvections would fix these points, my attempt at a characterization failed because products of transvections that do not fix $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$ may still fix $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$. I tried to consider when 2 products of transvections would be in the two-point stabilizer, then 3, and so on, but a full characterization remains elusive.

I would greatly appreciate such an explicit description of $Sp(2k,2)_{\theta_a,\theta_b}$, an idea on how to obtain such a description, or a reference from which to work.

Comment: I did some computer calculations for $2k=6,8,10$, and the answer seems to be that the $2$-point stabilizer is a maximal parabolic subgroup of the orthogonal group with structure $2^{2(k-1)}.{\rm GO}(2(k-1),2)$. I am sure this must be known, but I am afraid I don't know a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I also came across your answer from Overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/a/85094/172098. I ran some GAP programs and they turned out as predicted. However, may I know the details as to how you hand-computed some results? In particular, 1) how you determined that the 2-pt stabilizers were maximal parabolic subgroups, 2) that these were stabilizers of the isotropic pts of the maximal orthogonal subgroups,  and 3) that these acted transitively on those orthogonal and those not orthogonal to the fixed isotropic point?

Comment: I's forgotten about that!  I am afraid I cannot remember the details of the calculations. The $2$-transitive actions of ${\rm Sp}(2k,2)$ are described in Dixon & Mortimer's book on Permutation Groups, but I don't think the $2$-point stabilizers are considered. In fact they can be identified by their index in the orthogonal groups using the known information about the maximal subgroups of the orthogonal groups.

Comment: No worries. Thanks again for the response. Indeed, Dixon and Mortimer's book and their indices are what I used to locate them, and I think there's a paper from Bannai that tells us that the orthogonal subgroups of the symplectic group that we desire are precisely those with these indices. I figured out most of what I wanted though: that the symplectic groups act on quadratic forms and has two orbits O1 and O2, that the point stabilizer of a form q is the orthogonal group O(q) which acts transitively on O1 and O2 and where O1 and O2 correspond to the isotropic and anisotropic vectors of q.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out why the stabilizer of an isotropic vector $v$ under the action of O(q) would have two orbits: those consisting of the vectors orthogonal to it, and those that are not.